# Login Failed For 'Domain\User' SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: .net, active-directory, sql-server-2008-r2

Login user `sa` is activated and mixed authentication mode is enable, when the application (standalone .NET) is started from the user PC (domain user) the following error is raised

> Login Failed for user 'Domain\UserName'

In the connection string, `Integrated security` is `True`, and user Id is `sa`.

When I add the user to SQL Server logins, the application stars.

What can be the possible cause for such errors?

Answer (score 1):

You should use **either** the `Integrated Security=true` option (for using the Windows authentication of the currently logged on user), **OR** you should specify a separate `User Id` (and `Password`) to use a SQL Server login instead - but not **both** at the same time!

If you have `Integrated Security=true`, then the **currently logged in user account** will be used to try and connect to SQL Server with Windows authentication. But obviously, from your error message, that user does **not** have a Windows login on that SQL Server - therefore the login fails.

If you want to use a separate SQL Server login (and it's **strongly recommended** *NOT* to use `sa`!), you must supply `User Id=xxx` and `Pwd=yyy` and **not** supply `Integrated Security` in your connection string, to use the explicitly provided user credentials as SQL Server authentication logins instead.

Comment: the problem is i have to create every user in SQL security logins!!

Comment: @henokemolla: If you don't want to use the (generally preferred and recommended) Windows authentication  - then yes, every single user must be created as a SQL Server login.